# Check if Element with Specific className is Contained Selection

Tags: javascript, dom

Using [getSelection()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) to return a [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) object, I'd like to check if any of the elements contained in the Selection object have a specific className.

If, for example, I wanted the className of the Selection object's anchorNode or focusNode, I could just do something like `if (sel.anchorNode.parentElement.className === 'foo')`. But there's a good possibility that the element in question falls between the anchor and focus.

Just not sure how to access these nodes in between from the selection.

Comment: Just a thought here, could you get a list of the nodes with something along the lines of `document.getElementsByClassName('my-fancy-class')`, then loop through them checking -  [Selection.containsNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/containsNode)?

Comment: See the answer I posted. Tell me what you think.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though I can use:

```
if (sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneContents().querySelector('.foo')) {
    // Your selection contains an element with the className 'foo'
}
```

Does anyone have any objections to this?